# Javascript - Increase and decrease value based on another value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Very simply put, I have a variable `posnum` that its value ranges from 0 to 120.

What I need is a function that'll increase and decrease the opacity of another element based on the `ponsum` range of 0 to 120. So if the value of `posnum` is 120, the opacity of my element becomes 0, and if its value is 0, opacity is 1. I can do this with an easy if statement, but what about all the values in between? That's my problem.

This is my code at the moment and it has only got the if statement to cover the two conditions, but not everything in between. I'm working with the sly scrollbar by the way.

```
var frame = new Sly('.frame', options, {
    move: function() {
        var posnum = frame.pos.cur //this variable's int value ranges from 0 to 120
        if (posnum > 113) {$('#gradient').css('opacity', '0')}
        else {$('#gradient').css('opacity', '1');}
        }
}).init();
```

The code works fine and runs when I want it to, but it's just the dynamic reaction that I need for the opacity to change depending on where it is in that range.

Comment: How does opacity vary with posnum? Linearly? Cubically? Express opacity as a function of posnum

Comment: Linearly. How could I do that function? I believe it's something super easy but just can't wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var opacity = 1 - (posnum/120);
```

Assuming that opacity is directly proportional to `posnum`.

```js
for(var posnum = 0; posnum <= 120; posnum++) {
  var opacity = 1 - (posnum/120);
  console.log("Posnum: " + posnum, " Opacity: " + opacity);
}
```

Comment: It works beautifully. Thank you!
For reference:
`code`
var posnum = frame.pos.cur;
 var opacity = 1 - (posnum/120);
 $('#gradient').css('opacity', opacity)
}